# What practices are high cpu consuming inside a smart contract

Tags: cpu, execution-time

Eosio is a very powerful platform for developers, but resources seems to be precious, especially ram and cpu. Regarding to cpu time, what programming practices are commonly used in other platforms but should be avoided inside a smart contract because could be high cpu consuming?

For example, loops is the most basic example that comes to my mind. Looping large sequences of data would require time. What other practices should we avoid?

Answer (score 1):

In my Option a few things to avoid/to watch out for are:
- sending inline-actions and actions
- intensive mathematical calculations
- cryptografic functions (also intense mathematical calculations)
- heavy iterations, long running loops
- string manipulation
- working with floating-points

Answer (score 0):

Dan published a really great article about [Developing Efficient Contracts](https://medium.com/@bytemaster/developing-efficient-contracts-8a8e62011c6d)

You can actually read about the problems with Betdice dApp and how the usage of CPU can be reduced with a few optimizations :)